# How do you accept a javascript alert while using Ruby in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm attempting to click OK in a JavaScript alert that pops-up to delete an element on the page. I have the following:

```
assert element_present?(:css, "#add_foods_1 > table > tbody > tr > td.cf.cc2 > a.track_remove")
@driver.find_element(:css, "#add_foods_1 > table > tbody > tr > td.cf.cc2 > a.track_remove").click
assert_equal "This will delete this food from your foods eaten today.  Click OK to continue or Cancel to return.", close_alert_and_get_its_text()
```

And the defining code to call the `close_alert_and_get_its_text()` reads:

```
def close_alert_and_get_its_text(how, what)
  alert = @driver.switch_to().alert()
  alert_text = alert.text
  if (@accept_next_alert) then
    alert.accept()
  else
    alert.dismiss()
  end
  alert_text
  ensure
    @accept_next_alert = true
  end
```

I am confused on how to get tot he point of just clicking OK to close the alert. There is an OK and a Cancel on the alert.

Comment: this may help https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q%3a_Does_WebDriver_support_Javascript_alerts_and_prompts?

Comment: Thanks! I changed it to read @driver.switch_to.alert.accept and it is working fine now. Thanks, again!